# 2D polygon clipping

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have 2 polygons, one is always convex, the other can be convex or concave. Vertices on these polygons are sorted anti-clockwise.

```
for(int i = 0; i < sorted.Count; i++)
    {
        Vector2 start1 = sorted[i];
        Vector2 end1 = sorted[(i + 1) % sorted.Count];
        for(int j = 0; j < otherPolygon.Count; j++)
        {
            Vector2 start2 = otherPolygon[j];
            Vector2 end2 = otherPolygon[(j + 1) % otherPolygon.Count];

            Vector2 intersection = Intersection(start1, end1, start2, end2);
            if (!float.IsPositiveInfinity(intersection.x))
            {
                intersections.Add(intersection);
            }
        }
    }
```

Using this loop I can find the intersection points of the edges. The issue is that depending on where the convex polygon is, the order in which i find the intersection points changes. Is there a way to guarantee that the intersection points are always found in the same order?

EDIT: 
Example case -
2 Polygons A(sorted array in the code) and B(otherPolygon array in the code). A is static and can be concave. B is moving around and is always convex.

If B is on the right from the A and intersecting, then the intersection points are found clockwise order. If B is on the left the the intersections points are found in the anti-clockwise order.

Comment: Can you be more descriptive in what you mean by the intersection points being in "the same order"?  If the positions are different, the intersections are different.  Does same order mean clockwise/counterclockwise along the convex polygon, the test polygon, or something different entirely like they should be sorted by the `Vector2` values of the intersections themselves?

Comment: @Foggzie I wrote an example case where the issue is